# Group table values and add up the others

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, laravel

I have a mysql table with messages in. Each message has a status on its current status in the system. We want to generate charts comparing open messages vs the rest. I am trying to create a JSON response that looks as follows:

```
Roofing: [
   open: 12,
   others: 24
],
Building: [
   open: 4,
   others: 32
]
```

This is how the mysql database looks

```
+---+------------+---------+
|ID |  Industry  | Status  |
+---+------------+---------+
| 1 |  Building  | Sent    |
| 2 |  Building  | Review  |
| 3 |  Building  | Open    |
| 4 |  Roofing   | Sent    |
| 5 |  Roofing   | Review  |
| 6 |  Roofing   | Open    |
+---+------------+---------+
```

Sent and Review all fall under others

I need a way to count all the values for open and others and then lay it out in JSON.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An often overlooked feature of COUNT is that it actually counts NON null values only

```
SELECT industry, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Status  ='Open' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as open_count, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Status !='Open' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as other_count

  FROM Table1 GROUP BY industry
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to use `IFNULL(status, null)`

Comment: You are probably righ! I am in the habit of using CASE WHEN because IFNULL isn't in some of the other RDBMS i use

Comment: For oracle you can use `NVL` :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @e4c5 it is so close, how would you add review, sent together to give the value for other_count

Comment: that's what this query does. If you run it you will see that it shows 1,2 (which is the correct result for the data provided)

Comment: Yes it does. Apologies. Thanks so much for solving this for me, I have accepted the answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped.